# Show equivalence for different $n$

Tags: number-theory

Let $\{ a_1, \dots, a_n \}$ be a complete set of residues modulo $n$. How can we show that

$a_1+ \dots+ a_n\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$ if $n$ is odd, and

$a_1+ \dots+ a_n\equiv \frac{n}{2} \pmod{n}$ if $n$ is even?

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: $k$ and $-k$ are different residues when $n$ is odd.  They are for even $n$ as well, expect for one case...

Comment: Yes.  Since you can replace any element in those sums with any other element it is congruent to, you can start off by assuming you have a set of least positive residues.  You are likely familiar with the formula $1+2+\cdots+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$  Keep in mind that though $\frac{1}{2}$ may not be defined modulo $n$, depending on whether $n$ is even or odd, either $\frac{n}{2}$ or $\frac{n+1}{2}$ will be an integer.

Comment: But why does it hold that $a_1+\dots+a_n \equiv 0+1+2+ \dots+ (n-1)$ ?

Comment: It is because you have a complete set of residues.  It is true that if you just have any sum of $n$ numbers, then it won't be the same as $1+2+3+ \cdots + n$ (unless you get very lucky.)  However in a complete set of resides, no two numbers in the set can be equivalent to each other, and every number is equivalent to something in the set.  Thus one of the numbers must be equivalent to 1, one must be equivalent to 2, and so on.

Comment: Ah I see... So if we would have for example the set $\{ a_1, \dots, a_{\phi(n)}\}$ , we would have that $a_1+ \dots+ a_{\phi(n)} \equiv 1+ \dots+\phi(n) \pmod{n}$, right?

Comment: @user1390 Also, how do we get that $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} \equiv \frac{n}{2} \pmod{n}$ when $n$ is even?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ 0+1+2+...+(n-1) =\frac {n(n-1)}{2} $$

Notice that  $\frac {n(n-1)}{2}\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$  if $n$ is odd and  $\frac {n(n-1)}{2}\equiv n/2 \pmod{n}$  even if $n$ is even.

Comment: How do we get that $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} \equiv \frac{n}{2} \pmod{n}$ when $n$ is even?

Comment: $n=2k$, $\frac {n(n-1)} {2} =k(2k-1) = 2k(k-1)+k=(k-1)n+n/2$

Answer (score 2):

A quick hint: for any $k$ such that $1 \leq k < n$ consider $(n - k) + k$.

Comment: I haven't understood how we use the quantity $(n-k)+k$ to show the desired equivalences. Could you explain it further to me? @AlexNolte

Comment: For each of these pairs, their sums are $n$, hence $0 (\text{mod } n)$. What does this let us cancel?